# Prevent React Native App running until it has been updated with code-push

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I wanted to know if it is possible to prevent users from accessing any screen in app until code-push updates, Is this possible? if possible, could you please kindly show me an example, the goal is preventing the app to launch until update has been downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a state like `loading` to record if update has been downloaded.
In `render()`, return the normal app content only when `loading` is false. see my code below.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({loading: true});
  fetch(url).then(() => this.setState({loading: false})
}

render() {
  const {loading} = this.state;
  return (
    {loading && <Text>Loading</Text>}
    {!loading && <View>You normal app content</View>}
  )
}
```